# Are goals specified in the source code of a custom plugin?

Tags: maven

Are the permitted goals specified in the source code of a plugin? And can they be given any name we want as the developer of the plugin?

Tried to find the goals supported by a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are specified in the annotations in the source code.